# How to increase efficiency

Tags: java, performance, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I have the following homework question:
Suppose you are given two sequences S1 and S2 of n elements, possibly containing duplicates, on which a total order relation is defined. Describe an efficient algorithm for determining if S1 and S2 contain the same set of elements. Analyze the running time of this method

To solve this question I have compared elemements of the two arrays using retainAll and a HashSet.

```
Set1.retainAll(new HashSet<Integer>(Set2));
```

This would solve the problem in constant time.
Do I need to sort the two arrays before the retainAll step to increase efficiency?

Comment: Sort order is irrelevant for a hash-based collection.

Comment: To be honest, I see no algorithm in here so I think this will fail the assignment anyway.

Comment: `retainAll` if we have two distinct sequences `S1 = (1,2,3)` and `S2 = (1,1,2,3)` do you consider them to contain the same set of elements?

Comment: As always, start by looking at this _not_ as a programming question, but as a puzzle. Let's say I gave you two decks of cards, each with 200 items in it. I ask you whether they contain the same cards. How would you do it? Let's say I gave you two decks of 1000 cards -- what then? The question gives you a clue: you can sort the cards, as long as you tell me how long the sorting will take.

Comment: Not always does a single line mean time=1. The `HashSet` construction needs `O(n)` and so does `retainAll` (in general, it needs `O(n²)`, but with the `HashSet`, it's faster). Moreover, you line produces no result at all. `+++` In general, hashing is faster than using order, but you've been given comparable elements. So you're supposed to use the order.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect from the code you've posted that you are missing the point of the assignment. The idea is not to use a Java library to check if two collections are equal (for that you could use `collection1.equals(collections2)`. Rather the point is to come up with an algorithm for comparing the collections. The Java API does not specify an algorithm: it's hidden away in the implementation.

Without providing an answer, let me give you an example of an algorithm that would work, but is not necessarily efficient:

```
for each element in coll1
    if element not in coll2
        return false
    remove element from coll2
return coll2 is empty
```

The problem specifies that the sequences are ordered (i.e. total order relation is defined) which means you can do much better than the algorithm above.

In general if you are asked to demonstrate an algorithm it's best to stick with native data types and arrays - otherwise the implementation of a library class can significantly impact efficiency and hide the data you want to collect on the algorithm itself.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input, this is my new solution 1) Use two index variables i and j, set their initial values to 0
2) If S1[i] is less then than S2[j] the algorithm increments i.
3) If S1[i] is greater than S2[j] the algorithm increments j.
4) If both are same then print either one of them and the algorithm increments both I and j. I'm not sure how to avoid duplicates and make this more efficient. I think the algorithm takes O(m +n) time

Comment: @user9589242 If the two elements aren't equal you don't need to increment either index: at that point you know the sets don't contain the same elements. Also note that this assumes the sets are sorted first. Just because there exists an order relation doesn't mean it's been applied.

Comment: Thank you sprinter it makes sense now :)

Comment: @user9589242 Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue